# Find SAS controller that is well supported by the linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, scsi

**How can I find a SAS controller that is well supported by the official Linux kernel?** 
The controller should use the PCIe bus and needs to connect one LTO-6 tape drive.

I have looked through the kernel modules, but it is difficult to find a product in a shop matching the kernel module or to find out how well the device works with the module.

I would be interested in a website comparing the current status or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "Official Support of Linux Kernel". Linux Kernel accepts patches from many vendors, including Red Hat, Intel and even Microsoft (lol!). Eventually, `drivers/scsi` directory became full of that drivers.

You may try to cross-reference supported PCI IDs with names from database. Get supported ids with `modinfo`:

```
find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/scsi/ -name \*.ko -type f | 
      xargs /usr/sbin/modinfo | grep 'alias:[ ]*pci'
```

Than parse aliases (`v` is Vendor ID, `d` is device ID, `sv` and `sd` is subvendor/subdevice if exists):

```
alias:          pci:v00001028d00000001sv00001028sd00000001bc*sc*i*
```

and check in `/usr/share/pci.ids` (provided by hwdata).

I was managed to do this with this script: [scsisupport.py](https://gist.github.com/myaut/5cc023a91769b2503046)

As you can see, amount of data for that approach will be huge (you may also try to analyse commit activity, etc.), but I'd prefer an easy way - ask for users experience. My vote is for LSI.

Answer (score 0):

The only SAS controllers I've ever used were LSI ones. I like them for their quality and performance and also for their copious diagnostic information. I have reviewed all the other SAS drivers in the Linux kernel and none of them provide anything that is even close to what LSI has.

Not all of that diagnostic info is documented and some of that is downright buried but at least you can call LSI support and they'll be able to tell you more about the issue.

One example is the log_info codes, these give deeper info on IO errors and some of them are decode-able (I wrote a tool for that to simplify my life), not all of them are openly documented so some codes need to be asked about from LSI support. There are also the mptevents that one can track to find what happens on the SAS card and the fault codes that tell you what happened when the card locks up. There is also debug logs that the card can generate and they can be logged and analyzed by LSI support.

No one else comes even close to that.

My experience for using SAS HBAs is for hdds and ssds in large enterprise storage systems where I'm a software person but often tasked with understanding the problems of the hardware. All the above diagnostics is the only reason we can figure out most issues with ease after taking time to learn the topic.